# Splitting geom_dumbbell graph into multiple plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to build a dumbbell plot in ggplot, however, there's too many y factors and hence the y factors are overlapping.

Is there a solution to split it into multiple graph showing only 50 variable of y factor in 1 graph ?

Been looking at ggsave to increase plot size and also facet_grid option but are unable to come out with a solution

```
q3c %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x=year2005, xend=year2006, y=airport, group=airport)) + 
  geom_dumbbell(size=0.75, color="#b2b2b2", size_x=1.5, size_xend = 1.5, colour_x = "#DE4433", colour_xend = "#0171CE") + 
  labs(x=NULL, 
       y=NULL, 
       title="Dumbbell Chart", 
       subtitle="Number of Planes Flew: 2005 vs 2006", 
       caption="Source: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face="bold"),
        plot.background=element_rect(fill="#f7f7f7"),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="#f7f7f7"),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_line(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        legend.position="top",
        panel.border=element_blank())
```

[image: Current plot]

Comment: You could use one of the `facet_*()` functions, if you have in your data a way to differentiate different groups, for example, using the state where the airport is located. Otherwise, you might want to create a column that can group the rows, something along the lines of `a <- data.frame(x = letters[1:20])` and then `a$grp = rep(1:5, 4)`, then you can employ `grp` in a facet.

Comment: better solution: don't use a dumbbell chart, use a scatterplot - measurement 1 on x-axis, measurement 2 on y axis. label only a few important points (planes). You will have a much easier to read and informative graphic, your readers will thank you